# When should I fire an event to make my listview scroll to the bottom

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So in my Xamarin.Forms project I have a listview that is supposed to act like a list of messages, as in a messaging application.

In the constructor of my viewmodel, I fire off an async method to load in the messages, either from the server or from cache, depending on the situation. The problem with this is that the listview is scrolled to the top of the list, not the bottom like it should be. I can't scroll directly from the Viewmodel, because that would couple it to the view.

So, I thought, why not make an event and fire that when the messages have finished updating. This event works fine for when the messages update after the first time, but for the very first load it doesn't work. From liberal use of breakpoints I see that it does fire, but it seems to be before the ListView has finished rendering, and thusly doesn't actually scroll down.

Is there some "finished rendering" event I can hook into? Is there a place in the ViewModel I can fire my event knowing that rendering will be done? Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: you can write that on at the end of override OnAppearing() method

Comment: Additionally, the ListView has an ItemAppearing event that you can make use of in your view, in case you need to handle new messages.

Comment: C. Yu Yeah I tried hooking into the ItemAppearing event, but that seems to fire whenever a new item is scrolled into view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to time async stuff, so you indeed have the problem of being to fast. What you could do for example is subscribe to the event when your data is loaded inside the ObvservableCollection.

You can bind on the event in the behind code of your view and basically just do a scroll to the last item. This way you ensure you're on time to do this and aren't hassling with firing your own events.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

You need to have the CollectionChanged. Does this make sense to you?

So the code in your behind code of the view will be something like:

```
_viewModel.Collection.CollectionChanged += delegate()
{
   _listView.ScrollTo(_viewModel.Collection.Last(), ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
};
```

Comment: Yeah that seems to do the trick and is a lot simpler than what I was trying to do. Thanks :D

Comment: @Fireprufe15 no problem! Happy coding